# RewriteRule doesn't return valid result

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My first attempt was this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .*\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/assets/$1 [NC,L]
```

My second attempt:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/assets/$1 [NC,L]
```

But none of them works. This `.htaccess` file is on my every subdomain. My goal is when you enter URL like `http://foo.example.com/vendor/css/jquery-ui.css` or `http://bar.example.com/vendor/css/jquery-ui.css` both should return same content as `http://example.com/assets/vendor/css/jquery-ui.css`.

I have tested it on this website [htaccess Tester](http://htaccess.mwl.be/). On that website it returns valid URL, but when I upload it to the FTP, trying any subdomain will redirects me to `http://example.com/assets/jquery-ui.css`. It should't proceed just a file name but whole path and also without redirect, it has to "look alike".

Comment: Are you saying you have a separate `.htaccess` file for each subdomain? Or the same `.htaccess` file serves every subdomain? How is the main domain and the subdomains arranged on the filesystem? Do they point to the same place?

Comment: That file is same for all the subdomains, so there is one htaccess in every subdomain. Root for main page is same level as dirs for subdomains (dir `foo` is on the same dir as `index.php`). Don't ask me why, I haven't done it that way, I just have to test that functionality. But this situation should work just for subdomains `foo`, `bar` or whatever I choose, so that's why I add same htaccess in each subdomain.

Comment: Q1. Is `vendor` a fixed string? Q2. Do you have same `DocumentRoot` directory for all subdomains?

Comment: A1: No, there is much more dirs like that A2: No, there are also other subpages, which works as separated websites, I just want few of them to "share" their files. These few should work as static content.